# Hover Over Icon to Display a Caption Not Working Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so I have a row of image icons which are tightly packed into an area, and I want them to move up slightly when I hover over them, and fade in a title just below the icon. I've been able to successfully do this on my own site (can't link to it, sorry), except that I can't get the text to center below the icon and not affect the layout. I've tried positioning the title using position: absolute, but that uncenters the text below the icon. Without the absolute positioning, when it fades in it screws up the rest of the layout. I would just manually position each label using absolute positioning, but our web app is internationalized, so the words will be different lengths, so this needs to be dynamic. I tried creating a jsfiddle to show what I was doing, but apparently hover doesn't work in it?

http://jsfiddle.net/QYDmM/

Hope someone can help!

Comment: What browser are you using? The jsfiddle hover is working for me

Comment: The point is the text is not centered.

Comment: As a side note I realized my hover wasn't working due to a script blocking plugin in firefox. That's now been removed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/QYDmM/3/

What I changed is I added a new line to the jQuery and added `position: relative;` on `.icon-holder`.